# What precedents specify the scales of compensation for false arrest, and how would one set about finding them?

Tags: england-and-wales, precedent, case-law, compensation, false-arrest

According to an unreferenced [law firm’s website](https://www.thompsons.law/services/actions-against-the-police/wrongful-arrest-and-false-imprisonment#:%7E:text=If%20your%20arrest%20is%20unlawful,may%20be%20entitled%20to%20compensation.),

> As a general guideline, you may be able to claim around £870 for the first hour of false imprisonment, which increases to around £5,210 for 24 hours.

> In some cases, you may also be entitled to claim aggravated and exemplary damages, however it is rare for these to be awarded.
> Aggravated damages can be awarded where the police have deliberately acted to cause injury to feelings or where basic damages are insufficient.

> Exemplary damages are damages meant to punish the police for oppressive, arbitrary or unconstitutional action.

What case(s) lay(s) down these figures, and which set(s) out the parameters of exemplary and/or aggravated damages in such cases?